# Process form only if sent by server

Tags: php, html, forms

I have some pages in my web app which deal with the sent data from a form. I want to avoid the following situation:

An user creates (in the client side) a form with the same fields that my original form and sends it to the url which process the forms. Then, my process page receives the form sent by the user and processes it.

Is there any way to do that only forms sent via my web application get processed?

Comment: i suppose that you mean `csrf` protection?!

Answer (score 0):

An easy way is to generate a random token, set that in a session variable when you generate the form and add is as a hidden field to the form.

When the form is sumbmitted, you can check the session variable against the form field value.

That ensures that a visitor would need to request the form first but of course they could still to that programmatically, get the token and add that to the form submission.

Are the users not authenticated?

Comment: Yes, the user are authenticated. But I guess they can log in, let the browser open, and create the form. What I dont understand about reply is what prevents user from viewing source code, copying the hidden field (with the random token value) and adding it to his fake form

Comment: @Charles Nothing, it just requires them to open the form first. They can always make a POST or GET request sending anything they want and as you cannot rely on the referrer as they can set that themselves, this is about as much as you can do. What is the problem exactly with them generating forms? You would need to validate your data any way.

Comment: So if in a form I have an input field (eg: id_task) that sends an 'id' that must be deleted, if user creates a local form with same information but changing the 'id_task' he is going to delete another 'task' right? Then looks like I need some kind of ownership to prevent that. Thank you for you help @jeroen

Comment: @Charles Yes, you definitely need some kind of ownership for that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to research around [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery). There are many articles detailing how to go about that, see below:

1. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet
2. http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2013/02/preventing-csrf-attacks.html